# Checking remaining seconds on Laravel cookie?

Tags: php, laravel

Can someone tell me how I can check how long left on a cookie that I have set on Laravel? The documentation shows nothing on how to do this. I would like to stick to using the Laravel's cookie class for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to achieve, but the cookie expiration date can be set in another cookie. This cookie can then be read later to get the expiration date. Maybe there is a better way, but this is one of the methods to solve your problem.

> **Microsoft says:** "The browser is responsible for managing cookies, and
>   the cookie's expiration time and date help the browser manage its
>   store of cookies. Therefore, although you can read the name and value
>   of a cookie, you cannot read the cookie's expiration date and time.
>   When the browser sends cookie information to the server, the browser
>   does not include the expiration information."

[Helper link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194(v=vs.100).aspx), [Helper link 2](https://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/486298-get-cookie-expiry-time)

Add an extra cookie on time of laravel cookie creation as:
Putting an encoded json inside the cookie to get properly formated data out of a cookie.
Try that:

```
$expiry = time() + 12345;
$data = (object) array( "value1" => "data 1", "value2" => "data 2" );
$cookieData = (object) array( "data" => $data, "expiry" => $expiry );
setcookie( "cookiename", json_encode( $cookieData ), $expiry );
```

then when you get your cookie next time:

```
$cookie = json_decode( $_COOKIE[ "cookiename" ] );
```

you can simply extract the expiry time, which was inserted as data inside the cookie itself..

```
$expiry = $cookie->expiry;
```

and additionally the data which will come out as a usable object :)

```
$data = $cookie->data;
$value1 = $cookie->data->value1;
```

Much neater way to use cookies, because you can nest as many small objects within other objects as you wish!

Thanks to @Braikar & @Thariama for there research on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to achieve, but the cookie expiration date can be set in another cookie. This cookie can then be read later to get the expiration date. Maybe there is a better way, but this is one of the methods to solve your problem.
for example

```
// set
$lifetime = time()+3600;
\Cookie::make('userInterstitial', 'submit', $lifetime, '/');

// get
if (isset($_COOKIE["userInterstitial"])) {
list($value, $lifetime) = explode("|", $_COOKIE["userInterstitial"]);
}
```